# Deriving the E-Step and M-Steps of the EM-Algorithm?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-approximation

> Insects of a certain species were exposed to cold temperature and how
> long the insects survived was recorded. The survival times of 9 of the
> 10 insects, in hours, are given below.
>
> 0.8, 0.6, 3.7, 5.3, 0.9, 3.4, 0.4, 6.8, 5.3
>
> The experiment was stopped after 7 hours with one insect surviving
> longer than 7 hours.
>
> (i) If survival times are assumed to follow the distribution f(x) = λ
> exp(−λx), x > 0, λ > 0 find the maximum likelihood estimate of λ.
>
> (ii) The standard error of λ is calculated to be 0.09. Suppose we
> actually want an estimate of the mean survival time, µ, and its
> standard error. Write down the estimate of the mean survival time and
> use the delta method to find an approximate standard error of µ.
>
> (iii) Explain what the EM-algorithm is and how it can be used with
> censored data.
>
> (iv) Derive the E-step and M-step for this example

I've done (i), (ii), and (iii):

(i) $\hat{\lambda} = 5/19$
(ii) se$(\hat{\mu}) = 1.2996$
(iii) Maximisation algorithm used for finding MLEs. Iteratively finds the expectation and maximisation of the incomplete data.

But I cannot figure out how to get the E-Step at all!
I started trying to find E[loglik($\lambda$)] but I just ended up in a muddle.

Any help with understanding how to find the E-Step for this data would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

I feel like I'm getting somewhere:

> The missing data is the time for insect 10, $x_{10}$. We assume this is known and set $x_{10} = s$.
>
> $g(y|\lambda) = p(Y=s) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{9} p(Y=y_i)$
> $= \lambda exp(-s\lambda) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{9} \lambda exp(-\lambda y_i)$
> $= \lambda^{10} exp(-s\lambda) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{9} exp(-\lambda y_i)$
>
> $log(g(y|\lambda) = 10log(\lambda)-s\lambda- \sum_{i=1}^9 \lambda y_i $
> $= 10log(\lambda) - \lambda(s+27.2)$

I'm slightly confused from here though. Do I simply put $E(s) = P(Y=s) = 1/\lambda$ and hence $s^{(m)} = 1/\lambda^{(m-1)}$ ?

EDIT 2:
From this link: http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/EM_slides.pdf
$E[Y|Y>s] = s + 1/\lambda$ hence $s^{(m)} = s^{(m-1)} - 1/\lambda^{(m)}$ and I think we might have our answer!